# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/javax.mail.jar (Permission denied)

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-mail

I have one web app with login feature on my ubuntu system. I recently tried to add a `forgot password`-functionality to it for which I created a servlet to send passwords as email. Tomcat was working perfectly with other servlets, but when I added the servlet(Mail sender) mapping to `web.xml` and restarted Tomcat, it throws the below exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/javax.mail.jar (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.addSystemResource(ExtensionValidator.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.addFolderList(ExtensionValidator.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.<clinit>(ExtensionValidator.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:798)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
```

The things I did:

1. Used gmail's SMTP server for sending email
2. Installed javamail API
3. Compiled the mailer servlet and it was successful

I don't understand why adding the servlet to `web.xml` causes problems and how they could be overcome?

Comment: Please provide your stack trace, exceptions ,errors

Comment: You have to examine (and post) the tomcat logs for anyone to help.

Comment: post your servlet send mail

Comment: Downvotes ?? Bad Question ?? Am I being rude ? or Anything else ? Please explain!

Comment: @Anil There are no errors . Its just that tomcat doesn't work when I add the servlet to web.xml. I have tested email sender as a standalone program and it worked so it might be something with the configuration or else which I am unable to figure out

Comment: @Abdelhak Why does it have to do anything with the servlet when the tomcat doesn't even loads a simple html page in the app without triggering any servlet .

Comment: @rohit shrivastava Have you checked the file permissions on javax.mail.jar? It looks like the Tomcat user does not have read permissions.

Comment: paste `ll /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/javax.mail.jar`

Comment: Stop. Ignore above comments as to permissions, undo/cleanup everything you did and start from scratch by following Tomcat's own manual as to properly installing and configuring JavaMail: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions

Answer (score -1):

Your /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/javax.mail.jar file seems to have a permission problem and not be readable by the Jvm running Tomcat process.

Did you install it manually ?
Compare with permissions of the other jars in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/